# jQuery .val() ignoring first character of input

Tags: jquery, input, addeventlistener, event-listener

I have an input and a label. I want to show the label when the user types anything in the input box. However, as you can see in the snippet (or on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e0r2Lby4/)), the first character you type in the input box is ignored and you need to type another one in order for the value to not be empty.

```js
$('input').on('change paste keydown', function(event) {
    var inputID = event.target.id;
    var value = $('#' + inputID).val();
    $('#' + inputID + 'Label').css('visibility', 'visible');   

    if (value == ''){
        $('#' + inputID + 'Label').css('visibility', 'hidden');
    }
})
```

```css
#input1Label { visibility: hidden; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label id='input1Label'>Label</label>
<input id='input1'>
```

Comment: `keydown` is triggered _before_ the value of the input is changed, hence `value` is empty on the first `keydown`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Listen for `input` instead.

`keydown`, as its name implies, triggers before the key is lifted and, crucially for you, before the value is updated.

`input` not only has the benefit of covering all three of the events you're currently listening for, but also fires *after* the value is updated, meaning you'll get the latest value.

```
$('input').on('input', event => {
    let inputID = event.target.id;
    $('#'+inputID+'Label').css('visibility', $('#'+inputID).val() ? 'visibile' : 'hidden');
})
```

Answer (score 1):

`keydown` is triggered before the value of the `input` changed thats why you are getting an empty `value` for the first time.

You should change it to `keyup` event, which is triggered after the key is released.

```js
$('input').on('change paste keyup', function(event) {
  var inputID = event.target.id;
  var value = $('#' + inputID).val();
  $('#' + inputID + 'Label').css('visibility', 'visible');

  if (value == '') {
    $('#' + inputID + 'Label').css('visibility', 'hidden');
  }
})
```

```css
#input1Label {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label id='input1Label'>Label</label>
<input id='input1'>
```